# CSS -icons hidden on mobile but not on web

Tags: css, media-queries

I want the icons to only hide and appear on the web when the window size is set to mobile size with media query. What is there for it

Comment: You need to read the docs [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: How do you define window size mobile (i.e do you mean mobile or do you mean viewport size being less than something width or heightwise)? Once you know that look at the MDN documentation on media queries. For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

These are the boostrap 5 media query break points

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

// XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up)
@media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }
```

so you can add like below

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
#icon_id {
  display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:none` inside the corresponding media query,